# Unable to retrieve git stash - file does not merge even after repeated attempts and commits

Tags: git

I was on my specific branch and made some changes - but was notified that there were changes i needed to pick from master.

1. So I switched to master:

   - `git checkout master`
   - `git pull`
   - `git checkout my_branch`
2. Then I merged:

   - `git merge master`
3. Then I tried to pop my stash:

   - `git stash pop`

But it failed with following message:

```
Auto-merging /file1
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file1
Auto-merging /file2
The stash entry is kept in case you need it again.
```

5. So, I merged the file - /file1 by editing in editor. Added /file1 and committed
6. Then I tried to pop stash:

   - `git stash pop`

But it failed again with following message:

```
Auto-merging /file1
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file1
Auto-merging /file2
The stash entry is kept in case you need it again.
```

No matter how many times I committed /file1 - i got stuck in the same loop.

I also tried to branch my stash:

- Resolve the merge
- Add / commit all resolved files
- Try and branch the stash - does not work:

  ```
  c:>git stash branch stash_branch

  error: you need to resolve your current index first

  file1: needs merge
  ```
- Reverting to head also did not appear to be successful

  ```
  C:>git revert HEAD
  error: Reverting is not possible because you have unmerged files.
  hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
  hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
  fatal: revert failed
  ```

I badly want my stash back - is there someway or have I lost my stash completely?

I have tried resetting the merge and other solutions suggested but to no avail. Seems like I have lost all my stash.

Comment: I think I'm not understanding... if you pop the stash and it conflicts, it still loads the (conflicting) changes to the work tree and index as though for a conflicted merge.  So if you then resolved the conflict, your stashed changes should be present.  Are you seeing that changes were not in fact restored?

Comment: Yes @MarkAdelsberger - that's what I observed - no stash changes recovered - maybe I am doing something wrong here but I am unable to identify - all steps mentioned above followed exactly

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like the only thing you did wrong here was keep trying to re-apply the leftover stash.  Remember, `git stash pop` means: *Run `git stash apply`.  If it succeeds, run `git stash drop`.*

Your `git stash apply` is *failing*, not *succeeding*.  So `git stash drop` never happens—which is all as intended.

When a merge fails—regardless of how you invoked the merge—*you* are responsible for cleaning up the mess.  Git has done as much as it can for you.  Everything else is up to you.  So that got you to your step 5:

> So, I merged the file - /file1 by editing in editor. Added /file1 and committed

That completed the `git stash apply` (the "added file1"<sup>1</sup> part).  You made a new commit, which is also fine, though note that by omitting `git add file2` you *did not* commit the updated file2 that `git stash apply` successfully merged on its own.

But then you went back at step 6 to try to re-apply the stash again.  All you need to do, if you're satisified that everything from the `git stash` step is saved, is *drop* the stash with `git stash drop`.

If you're *not* satisfied that everything is saved, keep the stash, or turn it into its own separate branch using `git stash branch`.

---

I changed this to "file1", not "/file1", as file paths in Git should almost never start with `/`.

Comment: yes /file1 is actually representing the actual file path which is proprietary, it does not start with /

Comment: I once again resolved all the merges and added and committed `file1` and `file2`. Followed by attempt to create stash branch but still issue persists -- its not allowing to branch stash `c:>git stash branch stash_branch
error: you need to resolve your current index first
file1: needs merge`.

Comment: `git add file` is how you mark the conflict resolved (after, of course, resolving the conflict). It's a good idea to commit everything once you're done, before starting with more branches, though if you don't want to commit, you can `git stash` again (which then makes it harder to pick out which stash is which—this is why I rarely use `git stash` at all).

Comment: ok this works - thanks @torek - i mashed up changes across  multiple stashes

Answer (score 1):

finally I end up committing new changes then pop stashed changes, then resolve conflicts!